# Where I can find source code of deepEqual() function, that returns true in specific arguments?

Tags: javascript

NodeJS function assert.deepEqual() works as assert.equal(), but can compare arrays, maps, sets and objects recursively.

For example,

```
let m1 = new Map([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[3,4],[1,2]]]);
console.log(m1);
// => Map(2) { [ 1, 2 ] => [ 3, 4 ], [ 3, 4 ] => [ 1, 2 ] }

let m2 = new Map([[[3,4],[1,2]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]);
console.log(m2);
// => Map(2) { [ 3, 4 ] => [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] => [ 3, 4 ] }

// Where can I find this function? 
deepEqual(m1,m2) // => true

let s1 = new Set([[1,2],[3,4]]);
console.log(s1);
// => Set(2) { [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] }

let s2 = new Set([[3,4],[1,2]]);
console.log(s2);
// => Set(2) { [ 3, 4 ], [ 1, 2 ] }

// Where can I find this function? 
deepEqual(s1,s2) // => true
```

The above examples do not work with the standard [assert.deepEqual](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepequal_actual_expected_message) function of the nodejs module.

Ideally, the function should recursively check the equivalence of arguments. But because of the broken order of values, the function does not find their equivalence.

I found this in documentation

**[Comparison details](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_comparison_details_1)**

- Primitive values are compared using the SameValue Comparison, used by Object.is().
- Type tags of objects should be the same.
- Prototype of objects are compared using the Strict Equality Comparison.
- **Only enumerable "own" properties are considered.**
- Error names and messages are always compared, even if these are not enumerable properties.
- Enumerable own Symbol properties are compared as well.
- Object wrappers are compared both as objects and unwrapped values.
- Object properties are compared unordered.
- **Map keys and Set items are compared unordered.**
- Recursion stops when both sides differ or both sides encounter a circular reference.
- WeakMap and WeakSet comparison does not rely on their values. See below for further details.

This implementation is not suitable for looking for equivalence in such situations.

Comment: `deepEqual` is not part of any standard JavaScript runtime that I'm familiar with. Can you elaborate on your development/execution environment a bit?

Comment: There is one [assert.deepEqual](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepequal_actual_expected_message) in standard nodejs module. But this function cause exception on that examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're talking about `assert.deepEqual`. If so, then you should be able to figure out the implementation of deepEqual by acessing Node's documentation, and checking out the Module's information.

In this case, [Assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert). Once accessing this, you'll see a link to the actual **source code**, which points to [libs/assert](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.10.0/lib/assert.js).

If this is not what you're looking for, please provide more information on your question, so other people may also be able to understand and reply accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this very function prompted me to search for its analogues. Unfortunately, the above examples cause an exception, because the maps and sets are unequal.

Comment: I tried to explain the problem, but my English is very bad.